# Flutter: Text overflow ellipsis with three dots in the middle of the text

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to set the overflow dots to middle of the text in Flutter?

A normal use case is displaying filenames where the file extension is also visible to the user.

i.e.,
Currently, by using `Text` widget with `overflow` parameter as `TextOverflow.ellipsis`, we are getting the following

```
Text(
    "IMG_100232321321312312312312312321321312321343024.PNG",
    maxLines: 1,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
);
```

The result will be something like:

> IMG_10023232132131...

Is there any way can we get a result like this:

> IMG_10023...3024.PNG

Answer (score 6):

You can use **path library** like this:

> import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

```
   var data = "IMG_100232321321312312312312312321321312321343024.PNG";


          Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    data.split(path.extension(data))[0],
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  path.extension(data),
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                ),
              ],
            )
```

Answer (score 4):

Could do something like this..

```
Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Spacer(),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            fileName.length > 8 ? fileName.substring(0, fileName.length - 8) : fileName,
            maxLines: 1,
            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            fileName.length > 8 ? fileName.substring(fileName.length - 8) : '',
            maxLines: 1,
            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
      ],
)
```

Comment: overlapping? I didn't understand. The 2 texts widgtes would never overlap. Did I understand your point correctly?

Comment: no it won't. We are cutting the original text into 2 pieces and giving 1 to each `Text` widgets.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve that by this code.

```
class TextWithMidEllipsis extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;
  final TextStyle style;
  final TextAlign? textAlign;
  const TextWithMidEllipsis(
    this.data, {
    Key? key,
    this.textAlign,
    this.style = const TextStyle(),
  }) : super(key: key);

  final textDirection = TextDirection.ltr;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraint) {
        if (constraint.maxWidth <= _textSize(data, style).width && data.length > 10) {
          var endPart = data.trim().substring(data.length - 10); 
          return Row(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Text(
                  data.fixOverflowEllipsis,
                  style: style,
                  textAlign: textAlign,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  textDirection: textDirection,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                endPart,
                style: style,
                textDirection: textDirection,
                textAlign: textAlign,
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
        return Text(
          data,
          style: style,
          textAlign: textAlign,
          maxLines: 1,
          textDirection: textDirection,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Size _textSize(String text, TextStyle style) {
    final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: style,
      ),
      maxLines: 1,
      textDirection: textDirection,
    )..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: double.infinity);
    return textPainter.size;
  }
}
extension AppStringExtension on String {
  String get fixOverflowEllipsis =>
      Characters(this).replaceAll(Characters(''), Characters('\u{200B}')).toString();
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect code to implement the expected output. Thanks for sharing!